# Configuring file extension name in express handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, express-handlebars

I have a handlebars configuration

```
const path = require('path')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')

const morgan = require('morgan');
const multer = require('multer');
const express = require('express');
const erroHandler = require('errorhandler')
const routes = require('../routes/index');

module.exports = app => {

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80) 
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
    app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials' ),
        layoutDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
        helpers: require('../helpers')
    }))
    app.set('view engine', '.hbs');


    // middlewares
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(multer({dest: path.join(__dirname, '../public/upload/temp')}).single('image'))
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(express.json());

    //routes
    routes(app)

    // static files
    app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));


    // errorhandlers
    if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
        app.use(erroHandler)
    }

    return app;
}
```

but I get this error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Diesan
>   Romero\Desktop\redsocial\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

And this is my directories, what's wrong? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your handlebars files are using `.hbs` as the extension name, you need to define [`extName`](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#extname) properly when instantiating handlebars, like so:

```
exphbs.create({
    extname: '.hbs',
    // rest of options
})
```

Or to adapt your code:

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extName: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials' ),
    layoutDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    helpers: require('../helpers')
}))
```

Or just change your handlebars files extension as `filename.handlebars`.

Comment: Where I need to put that create function? inside the engine?

Comment: @DiesanRomero Edited.

Comment: @DiesanRomero Your `views` folder is within the `src` folder. Fix your filepaths as well.

Comment: I am trying to use this: path.join(__dirname, '../src/views') but I get the src folder two times, when I remove that, I dont get the folder. That's confusing me

Comment: @DiesanRomero How about: `path.join(__dirname, '../../src/views')` ?

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Comment: Hum, not sure then. I'm sorry these file path issues are not my strong point and I'm a bit short on time here to dive into it. Someone else might be able to help you. At least one of your issues is the `extName` so there's that.